# T-SQL select daily totals BUT daily cut off is not midnight

Tags: sql, t-sql, datetime

I need to count number of sales, and sum the totals of sales by date, easy. But the curve pitch is - I need the "cut off" to be 6pm not midnight.

> 6pm the day before until 6pm day of.

What's throwing me is "grouping".  My counts are only pulling only the true date not "6pm" info.

```
Sort30   Day30      Total                 Counter
-------- ---------- --------------------- -----------
20120810 08/10/2012 675.32                9
20120809 08/09/2012 1314.68               16
```

Query:

```
SELECT top 30 CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), chickendate, 112) AS varSort30, 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), chickendate, 101) AS varDay30,
SUM(CAST(transAmount AS money)) AS varTotal, 
Count(chickendate) AS varCounter
FROM CHICKEN
WHERE 
    (chickendate >= dateadd(hour, 18, dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, chickendate), -1))  AND 
    chickendate < dateadd(hour, 18, dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, chickendate), 0))) 
GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), chickendate, 112), 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), chickendate, 101)
ORDER BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), chickendate, 112) DESC
```

Going round and round, I feel its something staring me in the face.  Thanks.

Comment: Does the new "day" start at 6pm?  In other words, can you define the exact start and end time for 8/10/2012?

Comment: You are Filtering for a 24 hour period, which gives you two sperate days, but you are grouping just based on the day, which doesn't care the time.  I think you will need to add a calculated column based on the time to tell note its its day 1 or 2, then group by that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If chickendate is a DATETIME instead of just a DATE, then you can use

```
GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(hh, 6, chickendate), 101)
```

to advance the date 6 hours (making your cutoff 6 hours earlier than midnight, or 6pm), then group on the Day of year.  This only works if you're storing time information, which I'm not sure you are.  Post some schema for the necessary tables.  But I think you're looking for...

```
SELECT TOP 30 CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(hh, 6, chickendate), 101) as Date
        , SUM(CAST(transAmount as money)) AS Total
        , Count(*) as Counter
    FROM Chicken
    GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(hh, 6, chickendate), 101)
    ORDER BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(hh, 6, chickendate), 101) DESC
```

Answer (score 4):

If my logic is correct, this should give you the correct results:

```
SELECT TOP 30
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), modifiedChickenDate, 112) AS varSort30, 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), modifiedChickenDate, 101) AS varDay30,
    SUM(CAST(transAmount AS money)) AS varTotal, 
    COUNT(modifiedChickenDate) AS varCounter
FROM (
    SELECT
        transAmount,
        DATEADD(HOUR, 6, chickendate) AS modifiedChickenDate
    FROM CHICKEN
) sub
GROUP BY
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), modifiedChickenDate, 112) AS varSort30, 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), modifiedChickenDate, 101) AS varDay30,
ORDER BY
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), modifiedChickenDate, 112) AS varSort30
```

Comment: @Dems I don't believe so, but that's the part I'm not certain about.  The requirement `6pm the day before until 6pm day of` seems to indicate a `+6` if I'm reading it correctly.

Comment: No, @Dems.   -6 would make a 7pm sale be registered as 1pm in the new version.

Comment: Not `-6`. `-6` maps 6pm to noon, not midnight.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), dateadd(hour, 6, chickendate), 112)
```

So `'2012-08-09 18:00:00'` is grouped by `20120810`, and `'2012-08-09 17:59:59'` is grouped by `20120809`.